# Unable to locate element in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am working in Selenium. And I have got an error unable to locate element username. I'm using Java language. I am following page object design pattern.

Here is my code..

Pageobject

```
 @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\'user_name\']")
    WebElement username;
public void setUername(String usernam){
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'user_name\']")));
    username.sendKeys(usernam);
    }
```

Steps

```
AppointmentPage appointmentPageobj= PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.driver,AppointmentPage.class);

        appointmentPageobj.setUername(usernam);
```

Test

```
AppointmentPage ex=log.Valid("9845612345","naveen","nav@gmail.com","Demo","2017-03-04","Dr.biju");
```

Inspect locator:

```
<input type="text" id="user_name" value="" name="user_name" class="form-control">
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.4.0-64-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 193 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'naveen-Inspiron-3542', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-64-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.JfNimh}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=56.0.2924.87, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 650ae51248719121c19384d62127029c
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=username}
```

I tried to put the locators ID, NAME, XPATH and CSS too. But still same error is coming what to do?

Comment: is your element in an iFrame？

Comment: @YuZhang  no iFrame

Comment: I believe you should use this **`@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=".//*[@id='user_name']")`**

Comment: @Alok  yes I did @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=".//*[@id='user_name']")    same error is repeating

Comment: Are you waiting for the element to be present in the DOM before performing any action on it. **`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_details"))`**

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the page while inspecting the page? Also, make sure to check if it is inside the iframe. If it is then you might have to change the xpath from root of the document to the iframe to the element you are looking for. Your xpath looks correct, could be timing or something else that's causing the issue. Attach a screenshot of page, would be much easier to find the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your element is wrong by standard ways. Change as per below :

```
//*[@id='user_name']
```

In your code, change lines as per under  :

1. `@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id='user_name']")`
2. `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_name']")));`

> Xpath can not get element attribute with  double quote (") symbol. Use single quote (').

---

Let come to `Null Pointer exception`

**It might come for below scenario :**

driver is not initialize properly. So try to change below line with existing :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.driver, 60);
```

Use `DriverManager.driver` when you need `driver`.

Comment: please review my question

Comment: I have added answer please check

Comment: Actually this is my error Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}
  I edit my question please check

Comment: I tired by using Thread.sleep(1000)   still getting same error

Comment: Have you change element as per answer ?

Comment: This Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"} line says you are using this element name="username" . Find this line and replace name= "user_name"

Comment: @Sagar0077   @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\'user_name\']")    this is correct

Comment: what should I do ?  This is the line correct but I don't get the error

Comment: Have you find name="username" in your code?